# phonegap build add facebook plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am using phonegap build to create apk file for my app.

I am trying to inegrate the phonegap facebook app, but when I include it in the xml and update the code on phonegap build website, I get:

Error - Malformed config.xml

for all platforms.

my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.myApp.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>apname</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<!--<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />-->
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="331492342204" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="myGreatApp" />
</gap:plugin>
</widget>
```

my head tag includes:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script > 
    <script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!

needed to add in the  tag the following attribute:

```
xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
```

so this is the correct code:

```
 <widget id="com.my.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```